# Why does TI backup say there's still unnecessary cache?

Tags: titanium-backup, cache, dalvik

I noticed that the newer version of Titanium Backup says I still have unneeded Dalvik Cache to clean up, even after I reboot and wipe dalvik cache in Clockworkmod. Where are these extra cache files, and why aren't they in /data/dalvik-cache? Or, is this a bug in TI-backup?

Comment: Could it be you confuse "cache" (`/cache`, which you cleaned via CWM) and Dalvik-Cache (`/data/dalvik-cache`, which you also should be able to clean via CWM)?

Comment: Thanks, but I only have two empty folders in /cache.

Comment: OK, but that's not what TiBu complains about. Again: TiBu talks about **Dalvik** cache. You talk about **app** cache. Please read my previous comment again for clarification :)

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant - see edited question

Comment: Oh -- in that case it rather looks like TiBu got a little confused. I'd say contact Joël (the dev) and ask him directly (give him some details on your device/ROM etc, so he gets something to play with).